# How can I change the "click order" for overlapping buttons?

Tags: html, css, angular, user-interface, click

I have a project with two overlapping buttons: red button on the bottom, and yellow button on top.

The problem is that the yellow button "hides" part of the red button. I want it to be visible, yet unclickable. ***I need the red button on the bottom to be fully clickable, as if the yellow one on top did not exist.***

Can anyone help me out with the html/css code, please?

Project link available below.

Thank you.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-button-4xyvp6

Comment: you can use `z-index`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried giving Red button1 a z-index of 1 ("z-index: 1;"), and Yellow button2 a z-index of 0 ("z-index: 0;"), both in the CSS file, but it did not make a difference. Is this not the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pointer-events:none

> The pointer-events CSS property sets under what circumstances (if any)
>   a particular graphic element can become the target of pointer events.

```
.button2 {
    pointer-events: none;   
}
```

Forked Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-button-ahemot